# About Lightning McQueen's attempt to escape from Radiator Springs

Tags: plot-explanation, cars

How did Sally and the Sheriff end up *exactly* where McQueen would run out of gas, to the meter?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Doc Hudson had ample time to examine McQueen's motor and determine his likely fuel consumption rate, noting that the Doc is an ex-racer himself as well as a qualified Doctor of Internal Combustion. Sally and the others then siphoned Lightning's tank, which gives them the ability to determine (to the ml) how much fuel was returned to his tank.

From that point onwards you could just use an [extremely simple mathematical equation](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/002/054/706/b20.gif) to work out where he would be likely to stop *if he set off at full speed at the first possible opportunity,* which he obviously did.

> “Boy,” Sheriff said as he and Sally rolled out from behind the
> billboard, “we ain’t as dumb as you think we are.”
>
> **“We siphoned your gas while you were passed out,”** Sally added. She
> could hardly hide her grin. “Ka-chow!”
>
> <sub><sup>[Cars: Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/63947.Cars?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=UYqPsTiAOX&rank=1)</sup></sub>

Comment: Doc and a modern race car like McQueen likely get very different fuel economies, keeping McQueen below the threshold to get to the next gas station I could believe but getting the exact amount to stop right by the billboard is pretty far fetched

Comment: @ЖекаКрутой - The Doc is literally a doctor of Internal Combustion. If anyone can judge these things with precision it would be him...

Comment: If you think about it, McQueen only had to drive a little further than the billboard, there would be an intersection with a railroad crossing, and so he would return to the highway. He stopped only near a billboard, he was unlucky

Comment: @ЖекаКрутой - They had to hide behind the billboard so that he wouldn't go in a different direction. They only gave him enough fuel for less than a mile of driving, so he was fairly predictably going to head toward the town sign (think it clear) where they would be waiting.

Comment: Feel free to [ask](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) those as proper questions. 1, 3, 4 and 6 seem pretty answerable. 2 and 7 are just nitpicking continuity things.

Comment: What exactly did you mean when you spoke about an extremely simple mathematical equation? What exactly is the equation?

Comment: @ЖекаКрутой - I was joking. The formula is actually something like ***likely consumption per mile* divided by *volume of fuel = distance where he'll run out of gas***

Comment: Thanks for the reply, have a nice day)

Comment: Is it wrong to think of what "siphoning someone's gas" would represent in the Cars world? And that they all seemed to have a go, even taking it in turns?

Comment: @user25730 - cars in the Cars universe do not seem to die when they run out of gas. They just cannot drive anymore, precisely like cars (and their drivers) in the mundane world.